# Как отправить данные из динамической таблицы по soap

Tags: php, soap

Проблема заключается в следующем: есть динамическая таблица с 3 столбцами и неизвестным количеством строк (зависит от выбора пользователя).

Нужно передать по soa в Elma данные из этой таблицы. 
Как правильно это сделать?

Код SOA connector:

```
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.elma-bpm.ru/WFPWebService/"> 
<s:import namespace="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/"/>
<s:element name="Run">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="userName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="password" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="token" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="instanceName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="data" type="tns:WebData"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:complexType name="WebData">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Items" type="tns:ArrayOfWebDataItem"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfWebDataItem">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WebDataItem" nillable="true" type="tns:WebDataItem"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="WebDataItem">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Value" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Data" type="tns:WebData"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DataArray" type="tns:ArrayOfWebData"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfWebData">
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="WebData" nillable="true" type="tns:WebData"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

Реализация в php

```
$userName = ""; //логин пользователя от которого будет запущен процесс
$password =""; //пароль пользователя от которого будет запущен процесс
$token = ""; //токен процесса
$instanceName = $_POST['']; //название экземпляра процесса
$data = new stdClass();
$data->Items = new stdClass();
$data->Items->WebDataItem = array(); // Формируем массив контекстных переменных.
$data->Items->WebDataItem[0] = array("Name"=>"", "Value"=>$_POST['']);




// Массив параметров необходимых для запуска процесса
$parameters = array(
                    "userName"=>$userName, 
                    "password"=>$password, 
                    "token"=>$token, 
                    "instanceName"=>$instanceName,
                    "data"=>$data);

if($_POST[''])
{
// Создание SOAP-клиента по WSDL
$client = new SoapClient("http://.../Modules/EleWise.ELMA.Workflow.Processes.Web/WFPWebService.asmx?WSDL");
//Вызов метода Run для запуска экземпляра процесса
$client->Run($parameters);
```

Код таблицы:

```
<table name="Table" id="Table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">№</th>
                <th scope="col">Город</th>
                <th scope="col">Кол-во раб.мест</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="dynamic">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        <input type="text" name="col1" >
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        <input type="text" name="col2" >
                    </label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>
                        <input type="text" name="col3" >
                    </label>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="add">+</button>
                    <button type="button" class="del">-</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Взят отсюда: https://bitbucket.org/moskitos80/dynamictable/downloads/

Comment: избавьтесь от `table`, заверните в `form` и возрадуйтесь

Comment: Каким образом?) здесь такое условие, что нужно постоянно добавлять новые строки. Не представляю как это сделать просто в form.